# How to change uitextfield border when selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

How can I change the border of my uitextfield when it's selected or start to type some text in it

i try but it don't work check code

```
@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userName: UITextField!
```

whats wrong here no error but nothing happens

```
func fieldLayout () {

    if (self.password.isSelected == true) {
        self.password.layer.borderWidth = 4
        self.password.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.8362106681, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    }
    if (self.email.isSelected == true) {
        self.email.layer.borderWidth = 5
        self.email.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.8362106681, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    }
    if (self.userName.isSelected == true) {
        self.userName.layer.borderWidth = 5
        self.userName.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.8362106681, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to highlight TextField when user starts typing, I suggest you to use `UITextField` delegate method `textFieldDidBeginEditing` for handling when user starts typing.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == email {
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 4
        textField.layer.borderColor = // your color
    } else if ...
}
```

you can also use `textFieldDidEndEditing` delegate method for handling when user is done with typing

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textField.layer.borderWidth = // default width
    textField.layer.borderColor = // default color
}
```

So if you want to use these methods, don't forget to set `delegate` properties of your TextFields in `viewDidLoad` for example

```
email.delegate = self
password.delegate = self
userName.delegate = self
```

also don't forget to implement `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
```

Comment: `  func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == email {
            email.layer.borderWidth = 4
            email.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9254902005, green: 0.2352941185, blue: 0.1019607857, alpha: 1)
        } else {
            return
        }
    } `   tried it befor nothing happen also

Comment: @SemarY else is for other text fields

Comment: also make sure that you set delegates of your text fields

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
       // textField.borderStyle = .line
        textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor //your color
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
    }
```

You can check the textField tag and set the color accordingly.